# Thrift installation ./bootstrap configuration bad interpreter

Tags: hadoop, hbase, thrift, bigdata

When installing Thrift to access my hbase using different languages,

during the configuration when i am running

```
[hadoop@localhost thrift]$  ./bootstrap.sh
```

I get:

```
-bash: ./bootstrap.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

From reported error, it look like bootstrap.sh has some control characters (note ^M in error). May be bootstrap.sh need to be explicitly converted into unix format, you may use dos2unix command for this.

```
dos2unix ./bootstrap.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if the `#!` hashbang line of that file is corrupt.

Before using tools like `dos2unix` I'd rather check why that `^M` is there at all. That should not be the case, and it is very likely that the file has more defects.

If in doubt, try restoring `bootstrap.sh` [from the original source](https://thrift.apache.org/download).